# Problems using portproxy mapping on windows

Tags: windows, ip, netsh, networking, portmap

I have a server app installed on windows server 2012 called air video server which on installation attaches to my local address [::1] instead of my network address [192.168.0.3] on port 45631, I need the server to be reachable at 192.168.0.3:45631. I've looked for solutions and tried

```
netsh interface portproxy set v4tov6 listenaddress=[192.168.0.3] listenport=45631 connectaddress=[::1] connectport=45631
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Am I going the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The service in question is currently bound to the loopback interface. You should read the documentation for the program in question and figure out how to bind it to 192.168.0.3.

Doing what you are doing now is almost certainly not the right way.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation, but there is nothing about setting an alternative. it shouldn't be using the loopback interface, but it does, I know it's almost certainly not the right way, but am looking for a solution (even if it's a hack!)

Comment: Are you using the latest version? I just installed it on a test machine and it binds to `[::]` not `[::1]`